# Tortoise Overlay does not appear for mapped drives

Tags: tortoise-svn

I have tortoise installed on my development machine. Tortoise was installed on the staging server. I've committed my updates from the development environment and want to update staging. I've mapped a drive to the folder \server\c$\folder. I've changed my tortoise overlay settings to include mapped drives but the overlays still do not appear. If I logon locally on the server they appear, but not from my machine.

Thanks!

Comment: *> I've changed my tortoise overlay settings to include mapped drives*   By which you mean the option labeled `Network drives` right? Did you restart the shell/system since making the change? Does it show on local folders? Is there anything in your excluded folders list?

Comment: Corrected, I checked "Network Drives"

Comment: I did restart my computer since making the change. Local folders are fine. Nothing in my excluded folders list.